# Pinning based on origin of a reprepro repository

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt

I'm on Ubuntu 10.04, and trying to set up a repository using `reprepro`. I'd also like the pin everything in that repository to be preferred over anything else, even if packages are older versions. (It will only contain a select set of packages.)

However, I cannot seem to get the pinning to work, and believe it has something to do with the repository side of things, rather than the `apt` configuration on the client.

I've taken the following steps to set up my repository

- Installed a web server (my personal choice here is Cherokee),
- Created the directory `/var/www/apt/`,
- Created the file `conf/distributions`, like so:

  ```
  Origin: Shteef
  Label: Shteef
  Suite: lucid
  Version: 10.04
  Codename: lucid
  Architectures: i386 amd64 source
  Components: main
  Description: My personal repository
  ```
- Ran `reprepro export` from the `/var/www/apt/` directory.

Now on any other machine, I can add this (empty) repository over HTTP to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and run `apt-get update` without any errors:

```
Ign http://archive.lan lucid Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.lan/apt/ lucid/main Translation-en_US
Get:1 http://archive.lan lucid Release [2,244B]
Ign http://archive.lan lucid/main Packages
Ign http://archive.lan lucid/main Sources
Ign http://archive.lan lucid/main Packages
Ign http://archive.lan lucid/main Sources
Hit http://archive.lan lucid/main Packages
Hit http://archive.lan lucid/main Sources
```

In my case, now I want to use an old version of Asterisk, namely Asterisk 1.4. I rebuilt the `asterisk-1:1.4.21.2~dfsg-3ubuntu2.1` package from Ubuntu 9.04 (with some small changes to fix dependencies) and uploaded it to my repository.

At this point I can see the new package in `aptitude`, but it naturally prefers the newer Asterisk 1.6 currently in the Ubuntu 10.04 repositories. To try and fix that, I have created `/etc/apt/preferences.d/personal` like so:

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=Shteef
Pin-Priority: 1000
```

But when I try to install the `asterisk` package, it will still prefer the 1.6 version over my own 1.4 version. This is what `apt-cache policy asterisk` shows:

```
asterisk:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1:1.6.2.5-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     1:1.6.2.5-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe Packages
     1:1.4.21.2~dfsg-3ubuntu2.1shteef1 0
        500 http://archive.lan/apt/ lucid/main Packages
```

Clearly, it is not picking up my pin. In fact, when I run just `apt-cache policy`, I get the following:

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://archive.lan/apt/ lucid/main Packages
     origin archive.lan
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/multiverse Packages
     release v=10.04,o=Ubuntu,a=lucid-security,n=lucid,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin security.ubuntu.com
[...]
```

Unlike Ubuntu's repository, `apt` doesn't seem to pick up a `release`-line at all for my own repository. I'm suspecting this is the cause why I can't pin on `release o=Shteef` in my preferences file. But I can't find any noticable difference between my repository's `Release` files and Ubuntu's that would cause this.

Is there a step I've missed or mistake I've made in setting up my repository?

---

**UPDATED**

Thanks to some help by *maxb* on #ubuntu-server, I was able to find out some more about what's going on.

It looks like `apt` downloads package lists into `/var/lib/apt/lists/`. There's a subdirectory there called `partial`, which the manpage `apt-cache(8)` describes as:

```
Storage area for state information in transit.
```

But my repository `Release` file gets stuck in there, and is never copied to the parent `lists` directory. I can get the pinning to work if I do this step manually:

```
$ mv /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.lan* /var/lib/apt/lists/
$ rm -f /var/cache/apt/*.bin
$ apt-cache policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
1000 http://puppet.motto/apt/ lucid/main Packages
     release v=10.04,o=Motto,a=lucid,n=lucid,l=Motto,c=main
     origin puppet.motto
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/multiverse Packages
     release v=10.04,o=Ubuntu,a=lucid-security,n=lucid,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse
     origin security.ubuntu.com
[...]
```

But the manual step is undesirable, of course.

---

I also noticed that the `Sources` file is missing in my repository, but `Sources.gz` **is** generated. Recreating the `Sources` file by unzipping `Sources.gz` creates a file that matches the size and hashes in the `Release` file. But it doesn't appear to fix my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this by having `reprepro` sign the `Release` files. For reference, this is done with the `SignWith` option in `conf/distributions`, and is documented in the `reprepro(1)` manpage.

Comment: And, slightly unrelated, I also found out that `aptitude` (*not* `apt-get`) is buggy, and ignores `/etc/apt/preferences.d/`, only picking up pins in `/etc/apt/preferences`. (`pbuilder` uses `aptitude` by default.)